# Trying to delete a sheet and create a new ones

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run the program so that it deletes an already existing sheet, create a new one so that I can fill it with results. I want to be able to do this every time I run the program so that I get a new sheet without the previous results.

```
Dim CustomerID As Integer
Dim SameID As Integer
Dim TotalSpent As Currency
Dim HighSpenders As Integer
Dim CustomerOrder As Integer
Dim DataCell As Range
Dim ReportCell As Range
Dim UserAmount As Variant
Dim UserAmount1 As Integer
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsReport As Worksheet

Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Delete
On Error GoTo -1
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Do

    UserAmount = InputBox("Enter an amount")

    If Not IsNumeric(UserAmount) Then

    MsgBox "Enter a numeric value"

    Else
        UserAmount1 = CInt(UserAmount)
    End If
Loop While Not IsNumeric(UserAmount)

Set wsReport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Report"

Set DataCell = wsData.Range("A3")
Set ReportCell = wsReport.Range("A3")
```

Problem now is that it's not creating a new worksheet called Report with the results

Comment: Why don't you just Clear or ClearContents?

Comment: If you insist on deleting the *Report* worksheet and Adding a new one in its place, you should use application.displayalerts = false before deleting then application.displayalerts = true right after deleting.

Comment: The task requires me to delete previous existing worksheets

Comment: You re not Setting wsData or wsReport.

Comment: So what's the problem? It appears at first glance like that's exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

## Delete Sheet ft. On Error Goto 0

- If this code is in the `ActiveWorkbook`, you should use
  `ThisWorkbook` instead, or refer to it by its name e.g. `Workbooks(CreateReport.xlsm)`.
- Use the `With` statement for objects to make the code more readable and
  avoid unnecessary reference errors:

  The paremeter part of the `After` argument `After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)` ' is, I would say, incorrect and should have been:

  > `After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`.

  Why does it then still work correctly? It's because when omitting `ActiveWorkbook`, the `ActiveWorkbook` is actually used ('understood', 'default'). You could have omitted all the `ActiveWorkbook` references you used and all the `Sheets` would still have (correctly) referred to the `ActiveWorkbook`'s sheets.

  Why incorrect? You have decided to change all the `ActiveWorkbook` instances to `Workbooks("CreateReport.xlsm")`. You will probably not add the reference in the `After` argument, which could give you undesired results because it's referring to the `ActiveWorkbook`, which could be another workbook (not `CreateReport.xlsm`).

  The last part lead us to another benefit of using the `With` statement, namely if you want to change the reference of the workbook, you will have to change it only in the `With` statement (**once**) e.g.:

  > `With Workbooks("CreateReport.xlsm")`
- [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement)
  does **not** support `On Error Goto -1`, [Visual
  Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement)
  does. If you would have used

  > `On Error Goto 0`,

  the code would have produced `Run-time error '424': Object required` and would have highlighted the line `Set wsReport = ...` and you would have immediately known that this was the line that had to be changed.
- You can use the same variable `UserAmount` (as `Variant`) instead of
  `UserAmount1`. To prevent `Run-time error '6': Overflow` when entering
  a value that exceeds the `Integer` limit e.g. 32768, you should use
  `Long` instead of `Integer`:

  > `UserAmount = CLng(UserAmount)`

  ' or:

  `Dim UserAmount1 as Long`

  `...`

  `UserAmount1 = Clng(UserAmount)`

  if you'll stick with variable `UserAmount1`.
- You cannot Add a new worksheet and rename it in one go (in the same
  line). You have to use two lines:

  ```
  With ActiveWorkbook
      Set wsReport = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
  End With
  wsReport.Name = "Report"
  ```
- It is good practice to create titles or shortly describe various
  sections of the code. I've probably added too many.

### The Code

```
Sub AddSheet()

    Dim CustomerID As Integer
    Dim SameID As Integer
    Dim TotalSpent As Currency
    Dim HighSpenders As Integer
    Dim CustomerOrder As Integer
    Dim DataCell As Range
    Dim ReportCell As Range
    Dim UserAmount As Variant
    'Dim UserAmount1 As Long
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsReport As Worksheet

    ' If this code is in the ActiveWorkbook, use ThisWorkbook instead.
    With ThisWorkbook

        ' Create a reference to Data Sheet.
        Set wsData = .Sheets("Data")

        ' Delete (old) Report Sheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                .Sheets("Report").Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0 ' VBA doesn't support On Error Goto -1

        ' Input UserAmount.
        Do
            UserAmount = InputBox("Enter an amount")
            If Not IsNumeric(UserAmount) Then
                MsgBox "Enter a numeric value"
              Else
                ' You can use the same variable.
                ' To prevent "Run-time error '6': Overflow" when entering a
                ' value that exceeds the integer limit e.g. 32768, you have
                ' to use Long.
                UserAmount = CLng(UserAmount)
                'UserAmount1 = CLng(UserAmount)
            End If
        Loop While Not IsNumeric(UserAmount)

        ' Create a reference to a newly added sheet.
        Set wsReport = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))

    End With

    ' Rename the newly added sheet.
    wsReport.Name = "Report"

    ' Create references to cells "A3" of both worksheets.
    Set DataCell = wsData.Range("A3")
    Set ReportCell = wsReport.Range("A3")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You re not declaring or Setting wsData or wsReport. This will at least set wsReport to the newly created worksheet.

```
Dim CustomerID As Integer, SameCustomerID As Integer
Dim TotalSpent As Currency
Dim HighSpenders As Integer, CustomerOrder As Integer,  UserAmount1 As Integer
Dim DataCell As Range, ReportCell As Range
Dim UserAmount As Variant
dim wsData as worksheet, wsReport as worksheet

application.displayalerts = false    'do NOT ask for confirmation
on error resume next                 'if Reports doesn't exist, keep going
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Delete
on error goto -1                     'reset the error handler
application.displayalerts = true     'turn alerts back on

Do    
    UserAmount = InputBox("Enter an amount")

    If Not IsNumeric(UserAmount) Then    
        MsgBox "Enter a numeric value"    
    Else
        UserAmount1 = CInt(UserAmount)
    End If
Loop While Not IsNumeric(UserAmount)

set wsReport = ActiveWorkbook.workSheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
with wsReport
    .Name = "Report"
end with

Set ReportCell = wsReport.Range("A3")
'wsData is still not set to any worksheet
Set DataCell = wsData.Range("A3")
```